# How to make webview only load specific website like youtube?

Tags: html, swift, webview, youtube

I am new to Swift and I'm making an app with webview which can display youtube videos. My problem is I don't want my user to go to another url or something like that. I want to make my app load youtube.com. I'm using HTML instead of a URL because I can tell my webview what height and width it's going to have.

HTML code:

```
<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe frameBorder=\"0\" height=\"" + String(describing: height) + "\" width=\"" + String(describing: width) + "\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vid.videoId + "?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&frameborder=0&rel=0\"></iframe></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `shouldStartLoadWith` delegate method of `UIWebViewDelegate`

```
extension UIViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

    public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let url = request.url?.absoluteString ?? ""

        print("WebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest url -> \(url)")

        if !url.contains("youtube.com") {

            // avoid loading strange urls..
            // manage error as you need..
            webView.stopLoading()

            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Remember to set `UIViewController` as `UIWebView` delegate in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView.delegate = self
}
```